# Creating a new vector by aggregating another vector's value with a specific criterion in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, aggregation, transportation

I have a vector polygon layer in which each polygon represents an olive grove, each polygon has the data of harvestable biomass in that specific olive grove.

Now I have to estimate transport costs from the olive groves to a collection point by using a 17 tons truck. The problem is that the biomass value in each polygon are lower than 17 tons so I need to aggregate my polygons in a new shapefile in which there are more or less 17 tons.

How is it possible to perform this using QGIS?

Comment: So what you want to do is to combine neighboring groves until the combined harvestable biomass is above 17 tons? (I do not know (yet) how to do it, I just want to understand clearly)

Comment: As an afterthougt, I would think that you would like to go as close as possible up to 17 tons but not above if you want to use the trucks as efficently as possible?

Comment: Exactly for both comments, thank you...

Comment: And I guess you need to take into consideration the road network as well? It would not make sense to drive a 17tons truck a long distance extra to fill it up completely.. If so, I think you would end up with a kind of "Travelling salesman" problem.

Comment: Yes more or less it is like this... for the moment there is not the issue of excessive distance because the study area is still defined but for sure also this aspect is important for future development...

Comment: And how about reordering/regouping the polygons based on points inside them.  You could create # points per 100, 200, 300, ..., 1000, ... kg inside a polygon and then create polygons with a total of 17.000 kgs ?

Comment: I have only one value of biomass for each polygon, do you mean to assign this value to a point (like by creating centroid for the polygons)? And then regroup such points? In theory, if I understand correctly your comment, it can be a solution but however I don't know materially how to group polygons or points with the criterion "up to 17 tons"... I hope to have expressed myself in a clear way...